# How to modify HTML from another file with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a reference of a HTML element that has an id of `#searchResults`

```
  $.get('search-for-prospect', function() {
    _content.find('.prospect-container').sort(function(a,b){
        ...stuff...
    }).appendTo('#searchResults');
  })
```

I tried using jQuery's `get` to get the that element, but it doesn't work as expected.

I need to get a reference of `searchResults` and append to it. How can I achieve that?

Comment: That's a very odd thing to do. There's probably another solution but you would need to show a more complete version of you code before definitive advise could be offered.

Comment: You are not doing anything with data returned by `$.get()` and it is not clear which element is in other file and which is in the page already...or exactly what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get HTML from another page with javascript is by making AJAX call (in fact js template engines work this way).

So you have to `$.ajax` the page you want, parse it as HTML and do what you want to do.

Beware: you are not editing the HTML file itself, but just its "in memory copy".

Javascript, as far as it is used as client-side technology, does not allow modifying files or in general accessing the file system. So if you're looking for some trick to write in the HTML, you're on the wrong way

Comment: `$.get()` is a shortcut for `$.ajax()` so answer doesn't really make much sense

Comment: The important part is the rest :)